# Getting redirect to the authentication failure url when trying to authenticate with Spring Security + Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am having troubles implementing Spring Security along with Spring MVC and Hibernate.

When I give the credentials and validate the form, it goes to the following URL:
http: //localhost:8080/test/login_error.htm;jsessionid=9BE14BCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
So it redirects me to the login_error.htm page that I have configured in my spring-security.xml. It looks like a session has been created so the problems occurs after that.

I did try to debug to find out more and here is the deal:

Since UserDetailsService is configured as my authenticationProvider in my spring-security.xml, it goes into the findByUserName method in the UserDetailsServiceImpl class:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)

    throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        UserEntity userEntity = dao.findByName(username);

        if (userEntity == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found");

        return (UserDetails)assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(userEntity);

    }
```

When it goes to the return, the user is properly loaded, so the connection to the DB has been made and the user has been found, no issue on that side. I can't figure out where the problem is.

Here is the UserEntityDAOImpl class that I am using:

```
@Repository("userEntityDao")
public class UserEntityDAOImpl implements UserEntityDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void addUser(UserEntity user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

    public UserEntity findByName(String username) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        UserEntity user = (UserEntity)session.createQuery("select u from UserEntity u where u.username = '" + username + "'").uniqueResult();
        return user;
    }

...others methods like activate, listUsers, etc...
```

**Edit:**

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User buildUserFromUserEntity(UserEntity userEntity) {

        String username = userEntity.getUsername();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();
        boolean enabled = userEntity.getActive();
        boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.getActive();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.getActive();
        boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.getActive();

        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();

        for (SecurityRoleEntity role : userEntity.getSecurityRoleCollection()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        User user = new User(username, password, enabled,
        accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        return user;

    }

}
```

It is retrieving the roles properly from the DB (ROLE_Admin in my case).

Here is my spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_Admin')" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/home.htm" />

        <form-login login-page="/login.htm" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-failure-url="/login_error.htm" default-target-url="/home.htm"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="com.daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:property name="providers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref local="com.daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Here is the web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</servlet> -->

    <!-- This listener creates the root application Context -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your user doesn't have the required permissions (i.e. `Authorities`) set. Enable [Spring Security debug logging](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html). What does

```
assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(userEntity);
```

do? What do you see if in the `loadUserByUsername` method before returning you print `UserDetails-getAuthorities()` to the console?

Comment: I edited my initial post and added the content of the Assembler class. The roles associated to the user are properly retrieved from the DB.

Comment: printing UserDetails-getAuthorities(), I see [ROLE_User] when trying to login with a user having ROLE_User as a security role or [ROLE_Admin] when trying to login with a user having ROLE_Admin as a security role.

Comment: After following your advice and configuring log4j I realized that the reason the logging process wasn't going through was due to the fact that the user account was locked for some reason. This is because I was setting the accountNonLocked boolean base on the User I got out of my DB, but since I do not have any column for this it always ended up being set to false...